# Is there a way to skip first row in csv file, when it is a datasource for SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SSRS Dataset in my SSRS report, which is pulling data from a .csv file. The format of csv is as below.

```
Date:04/03/2019

Col1,Col2,Col3

111,222,333

444,555,666
```

I want to ignore the first row which is "Dates:4/9/2019" because of which the report is not able to pick up the actual data in col,col2 and col3.

Would anyone please help with a query or method to skip the first row in my dataset with SSRS report.

NOTE: I cannot use SSIS or SQL server to achive this as I am only dealing with SSRS and csv files.